# How to handle large data sets in Java without using too much memory

Tags: java

I'm working in Java. I have the requirement that I must essentially compare two database queries. To do this, I take each row of the result set and assign it to a HashTable with the field name as the 'key' and the data in the field as the 'value'. I then group the entire result set of HashTables into a single Vector just as a container. So essentially to compare two queries I'm really iterating through two Vectors of HashTables.

I've come to find that this approach works really well for me but requires a lot of memory. Because of other design requirements, I have to do this comparison via a Vector-HashTable-like structure, and not some DB side procedure.

Does anyone have any suggestions for optimization? The optimal solution would be one that is somewhat similar to what I am doing now as most of the code is already designed around it.

Thanks

Comment: If it is not the same database, this can't be done in SQL whitout merging it all back into yet another database.

Comment: i'd also use HashMap and ArrayList instead, to at least get rid of all of the synchronization overhead of the old old collection classes...

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. So far it seems like most people agree with the ArrayList of HashMaps approach. My HashMaps typically have about 8 key-value pairs; key's being about 10 chars long and values no longer than 30-50 characters long.

It's not uncommon to compare two ArrayLists with 10,000 HashMaps each. So that's 20,000 HashMaps in memory. Is that too much? 

Would it make more sense to just load up half of each ArrayList, then dispose of it and load the other half? Only problem is I'd have to dispose and load the halves about 4 times to compare them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the [**Flyweight Pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern)? Do you have lots of equal objects?

Perhaps this pattern might be appropriate for your 'Key', as I imagine the field names are going to be repeated for each row? If they're Strings, you can call `intern()` so that they'll share the same memory location with other equal Strings, as Strings are immutable.

Another possible optimization - not memory but speed - if concurrency is not an issue would be to use an `ArrayList` rather than a `Vector` - as they are not synchronized so accesses should be a little faster. Similarly, `HashMap` isn't synchronized and `Hashtable` is, so using the former might be faster too.

Comment: Careful with intern() - you might overflow that area.

Comment: @Thorbjørn : I had that problem once, and increasing the perm gen solved it in my specific case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094925/trying-to-solve-15-puzzle-outofmemoryerror/3095101#3095101

Comment: Is that a permanent solution or will the perm gen increment need to be adjusted if the resultsets grow even larger?

Comment: There are typically a lot of equal objects. I'll check out that pattern. The key names are indeed repeat a lot and often the value as well. The Hashtables that end up matching are never in the same memory location so I end up comparing key-values directly to find matching tables.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Works most of the times ( well I have only needed it 3 fortunately! :P )  But, of course, you're still limited to your physical RAM capacity. So, if you have 1g for perm gen and you create 2 gb of strings, you'll get out of memory anyway ( which you would have way lot sooner if you don't do it ) See the graphs. In that particular case the strings repeated **A LOT** so 25 mb of perm gen were needed where 2gb of non-interned string wasn't enough before.  For strings that differ too much, this doesn't work ( just like you point out )

Answer (score 6):

Specify the same `ORDER BY` clause (based on the "key") for both result sets. Then you only have to have one record from each result set in memory at once.

For example, say your results are `res1` and `res2`.

If the `key` field of `res1` is less than the `key` field of `res2`, `res2` is missing some records; iterate `res1` until its `key` field is equal to or greater than the `key` of `res2`.

Likewise, if the `key` field of `res1` is greater than the `key` field of `res2`, `res1` is missing some records; iterate `res2` instead.

If the `key` fields of the current records are equal, you can compare their values, then iterate both result sets.

You can see, in this manner, that only one record from each result is required to be held in memory at a given time.

Comment: i'd go with something like this, a "streaming" comparison, presuming you can order by to get them in the same order.

Comment: The problem is I'm not actually pulling from two databases but rather a database-like XML document that I have no control over the order of.

Comment: Then do the sorting yourself, writing the results to temporary files. If "main memory" isn't big enough, you fall back to mass storage. You know, all those great algorithms developed in the 50s and 60s for working with paper and magnetic tapes...

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify what kind of comparison do you need, but I would reduce the amount of data held by the HashMap/Vector  by transforming the row information into a single hash number.

Something like this:

```
class RowHash {
    private final int id;       // the row id 
    private final int hashCode; // summary of the whole row info 

    public RowHash( ResultSet rs ) {

        this.id = rs.getInt("id");
        // get the strings from all the data 
        this.hashCode = new StringBuilder()
                       .append( rs.getString("field1") )
                       .append( rs.getString("field2") ) 
                       .append(rs.getString("fieldN"))
                       .toString().hashCode();
    }
    public final boolean equals( Object other ) { 
        return this.hashCode() == other.hashCode();
    }
    public final int hasCode() {
       return hashCode;
    }   
}
```

And then store it into an ArrayList instead of a Vector which is not synchronized.

```
 ... 
 ResulSet rs = ... 
 while( rs.next() ) {
     arrayList.add( new RowHash( rs ) );
 }
```

Well that's the idea,  ( and depending on the comparison you need )   is to compute a number representing the whole record, and then use that single number to see if the other query has it.

Bear in mind that this is just a concept, you'll have to modify it to suit your needs.

Another ( probably simpler ) way to reduce the amount of memory used by a program that uses a lot of strings, is to call `intern()` .

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094925/trying-to-solve-15-puzzle-outofmemoryerror/3095101#3095101) to compare the impact, but really it depends in your data.

Heres a before/after screenshot  using `intern` on that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094925/trying-to-solve-15-puzzle-outofmemoryerror/3095101#3095101)

[image: before]

<sub>*Before*</sub>

[image: after]

<sub>*After*</sub>

Area in blue is memory used, in the first around 2gb in the second < 25 mb

Comment: Cool. I think parts of this could be helpful, but two HashTables are considered the same if there are certain key fields that match, so I think hashing the contents like that wouldn't work for me. Furthermore, I reference the keys in other parts of the program so I'd need the hash you suggest PLUS all the regular keys.

Comment: Yeap, it is very hard to answer without specific requirements. Probably you could do this first, without Map ( HashMap ) and get the id's for the the different rows, so instead of holding gigs in memory, you'll only hold the id's and then re-fetch only those records.  Again, it depends on your particular needs. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you can sort both of the queries results, you should adapt [sorted-merge join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort-merge_join) algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You could encapsulate your **own Object**, for instance, a 'MyRecord' which is smaller than a HashMap, then it will be a List of 'MyRecord'.

If you have to use HashMap, use **new HashMap(7,1)** instead of default constructor, that  could save memory, since you said fixed '8 key-value pairs' in a map

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have the memory you will need external storage backing your datastructure, which is hard to do correctly (maps of weak references to your data, which all need to be rolled out to disk, etc), and you probably still will end up with bad performance when scaling.

If you really have lots and lots of data, I would suggest embedding a SQL database.  Then you can generate two tables containing your data and ask the database to find out any differences, and drop the tables afterwards.  I've previously played with Derby, which I found nice, but others exist.

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset does not fit in to memory, then do an external sort, and after then the sort-merge join, as already pointed out in another answer.

If your dataset **does** fit in to memory, then just use a lot of memory - it's fastest that way.

Or if you are interested in specific optimizations just doing what you already do a little bit better - I can't help you.